# BigQuery use the where clause to filter on a column that not always exists in the table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to create some kind of a uniform query for multiple tables. Some tables contain a certain column with a type. If this is the case, I need to apply filtering to it. I don't know how to do this.

I have for example two tables

table_customer_1

```
CustomerId, CustomerType
1, 1
2, 1
3, 2
```

Table_customer_2

```
Customerid
4
5
6
```

The query needs to be something like the one below and should work for both tables (the table name wil be replaced by the customer that uses the query):

```
    With input1 as(
        SELECT
        (CASE WHEN exists(customerType) THEN customerType ELSE "0" END) as customerType, *
    FROM table_customer_1)
    SELECT * from input1
WHERE customerType != 2
```

Comment: You have a real data modeling problem if you want to filter by a column that is not present in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE SAFE_CAST(IFNULL(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '$.CustomerType'), '0') AS INT64) != 2
```

or as a simplification you can ignore casting to INT64 and use comparison to STRING

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
WHERE IFNULL(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '$.CustomerType'), '0') != '2'
```

above will work for whatever table you put instead of `project.dataset.table`: either `project.dataset.table_customer_1` or `project.dataset.table_customer_2` - so quite generic I think

Answer (score 0):

I can think of no good reason for doing this.  However, it is possible by playing with the scoping rules for subqueries:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (SELECT customerType  -- will choose from tt if available, otherwise x
              FROM table_customer_1 tt
              WHERE tt.Customerid = t.Customerid
             ) as customerType
      FROM (SELECT t.* EXCEPT (Customerid)
            FROM table_customer_1 t
           ) t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT 0 as customerType) x
     ) t
WHERE customerType <> 2
```